# I killed Magus in Chrono Trigger. Did I miss the opportunity to have him in my party?

Tags: nintendo-ds, chrono-trigger

I've been replaying Chrono Trigger on the DS and have gotten to the point after the Ocean Palace where you fight Magus for the second time.

I think I killed him...

Have I missed the opportunity to have him in my party?

Comment: Why do you think you've "killed" him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately yes. When you can choose whether to fight Magus or not, that decides whether he can join you or not.

> [After defeating the Blackbird [...] if Frog [or the Party] refuse [to fight Magus], Magus will join the party.](http://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/Magus#Magus_in_the_Party)

Comment: For that playthrough only. You should be able to recruit him again on the next go through.

Comment: More games need new game+